# Proving something is logically valid

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

This is a Question I tried to solve from a Mathmatical logic textbook:

*"Prove that B is a **Logical Consequence** of $A$<sub>$1$</sub>,$A$<sub>$2$</sub>,$A$<sub>$3$</sub>,...,$A$<sub>$n$</sub> **If and Only If** 

($A$<sub>$1$</sub> $\land$ $A$<sub>$2$</sub> $\land$ $A$<sub>$3$</sub>$\land$ ... $\land$ $A$<sub>$n$</sub> ) $\Rightarrow$  B  is **logically valid** "*

**My attempt**: First , I wanted to make the set of the  $L$-formulas that are given to me ,  $S$ = {$A$<sub>$1$</sub>,$A$<sub>$2$</sub>,$A$<sub>$3$</sub>,...,$A$<sub>$n$</sub>} 
This set $S$ is satisfiable by the set of assiqnments $M$<sub>$s$</sub> = {$M$<sub>$1$</sub>,$M$<sub>$2$</sub>,$M$<sub>$3$</sub>,....,$M$<sub>$m$</sub>}.At this point , I got stuck not knowing what to do next to prove the theorem above with these sets.It is kind of like hitting a wall for me.Can someone tell me what I am thinking wrong ? (should I use a truth table?)

Comment: What definition of "logcial consequence" do you have ? If it is just "$A\implies B$" nothing has to be proven. Also, you probably mean "true" instead of "logcially valid".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we work with propositional calculus, the definition of "logically valid" (aka: [tautology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)#Definition_and_examples)) and ["logical consequence"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tautology_(logic)#Tautological_implication) can be formalized with valuations, where a [valuation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valuation_(logic)) $v$ is a function from the set of sentential variables of the language to truth-values:

> $v : \text {SentVar} \to \{ \text T, \text F \}$.

For the first part of the proof (considering for simplicity $n=2$) : if $B$ is a logical consequence of $A_1, A_2$, this means that:

> for every valuation $v$ such that $v(A_1)= v(A_2)= \text T$, we have also $v(B)= \text T$.

Thus, there is no valuation $v$ such that $v(A_1)= v(A_2)= \text T$ and $v(B)= \text F$, that means that (see [truth table for conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_conditional#As_a_truth_function)):

> $v((A_1 \land A_2) \to B))= \text T$, for every valuation $v$.

And this means that $(A_1 \land A_2) \to B$ is a *tautology*.

The same for the other part of the proof.

Comment: Can you also show me how to extend this to $A2$